# linux troubleshoot connectivity issue but telnet working

Tags: linux, centos, activemq-classic

Am using ActiveMQ for message publish/subscribe where it accepts the connection from the publisher. But sometime all of sudden its not accepting any connection from publisher client though the service is still running. And telnet also works fine in that time for the ActiveMQ port, but I had to restart ActiveMQ service to make the connection happen from publisher client to publish message.

During that I had done the basic checks like CPU,Mem usage, load average and IO wait and all are fine. Any idea how can we troubleshoot to find out what is causing the connectivity issue?

Comment: you need to have a look in the activemq log file. Depending on your install its located at; `<your activemq install path>\data\activemq.log`

Comment: on activemq log file am not seeing errors at all. so I need to troubleshoot at network level or socket level.

Comment: do you have a firewall log you can check? and as I'm not sure what environment this is in - do you have any hardware firewall/risk filters infront of your AMQ box?